# i am trying to style the pipe sign as a separator for a link

Tags: css

Hey guys i am trying to style the pipe symbol(|) as a separator for a link, using the span tag. Yet it will not style.

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="http://www.myhome.com">Home<span class="separator">|</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.aboutme.com">About<span class="separator">|</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.contactus.com">Contact<span class="separator">|</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.learnmore.com">Learn more</a></li>
</ul>


<style>
 .separator{
 font-size: 1.5em;
  color: red;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: This should be closed as typographical error (offtopic)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Or it can be answered, which is much more useful for OP.

Comment: This is a Q&A community, not a forum. If the rules said that typographical errors are offtopic, this question is offtopic. No more.

Comment: @Macos, even with s typo, one can still learn interesting things. Don't you think ?

Comment: @pedroyanky what if the typo was indeed a `typo` by the user in this question and not in his work? What if there is more to it? Like other parts of the code messing with this

Comment: @Macos, we never really know. because in this case it seems to be from the work too. Thats why it obviously didn't work. In fact i thought semi colons are optional, because without it in the last property declaration, the code works quite fine

Comment: @pedroyanky this kind of questions solves with a comment: `You've missed a semicolon in this line...` and then closes as offtopic > typographical error. The user will have the solution, but we don't follow feeding an offtopic question. Remember that in this community all questions+answers needs to be useful to all people that read the topic. Miss a semicolon is not a useful question, including the bad subject of this question that doesn't describe the real error (missed the semicolon). I'm not talking about remove, I'm talking about close.

Comment: However, you've got 2 answers. You need to accept the correct one.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the semicolon:

```
 .separator{
     font-size: 1.5em; /* <= missing semicolon */
     color: red;
 }
```

Comment: I have a doubt. Is it better to use `:after` and `not(last)` to style this or do it like above with additional HTML. Which is better? I know this is not related to this question or the solution. Just curious

Comment: Well, this is the reason why it did not work. Using `:after` might work as well, in some cases it is better/cleaner in others it might not be. It entirely depends on the use case and the other styling.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using it in html, use it in a :pseudo element like :before or :after

```
li {
  position: relative;
}

li:before {
  content: '|';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

and yes, you missed the semicolon after `font-size: 1.5em;` as mentioned by @str

Comment: While it's true, using HTML is also fine, however this doesn't answer why OP has this problem.

Comment: @Lucian, your pseudo element declaration seems to be puzzling, why inclusion of the position property?

Comment: so that it won't take any space. you can use `inline-block` instead. it's your choice. all you need is `content: '|';`